# Commercial Java Web Services Framework

Tags: java, web-services

I know that there are alot of mature open source Java web services frameworks out there (Axis, Spring WS, Metro). But are there any commercial alternatives? Unfortunately our company has a strict open source policy :(

We're trying to build a simple web service client that talks to a .net asmx web service.

Comment: Metro is distributed by the vendor of the Java platform itself.  Curious what this "policy" is...   And if you honestly have to tie your hands behind your backs and avoid all that is Apache Jakarta, I weep for you.  Also, your company should learn about the difference between GPL and LGPL.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but wasn't there a company that simply sold Samba to companies with such policies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Service frameworks such as Axis 2, CXF, etc. Java 6 now supports [JAX-WS 2 (JSR 224)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224). Here's a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) (*Introducing JAX-WS 2.0 With the Java SE 6 Platform*) that shows you how to.

As for commercial, I don't really know any.